# How to create a custom shapes using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

For eg. I need to be able to create a key shape using CSS

[image]

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hoyubiredo/1/edit?html,css,output) for convenience

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question by posting that jsbin?

Comment: Your title says "how to", but your question says "is it possible". Assuming the latter, the answer is "yes". Assuming the former, the answer is "by writing a whole bunch of CSS rules with positioning and styling like colors". Personally, I wouldn't waste your time with this unless you're really having a hard time finding things to keep yourself busy.

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like this:

```css
#key {
  margin: 50px 0 0 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
#key:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
#key:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 30px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="key"></div>
```

Comment: This looks like the key shape I want but the styling needs to be done inside the section indicated in the image attached to the question. (I don't have control to modify the rest of the divs)